# login in jetpack compose(single event)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to call "onLogin" function and pass user but I can't access "onLogin" in ViewModel , I tried to use mutableLiveData but I couldn't,I don't know should I pass onLogin to viewmodel or this is a bad practice

there is button whose title is "Sign In" , it calls method in ViewModel called "Submit" use apollo  (graphql) to get the user

SignInScreen

```
@Composable
fun SignInScreen(
    onNavigateToSignUp:() -> Unit,
    onLogin:(User) -> Unit
){
    val viewModel:SignInViewModel = viewModel()
    
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(text = "Don't have an account?")
                Text(
                    text = "Sign Up.",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 5.dp)
                        .clickable { onNavigateToSignUp() },
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it),
            horizontalAlignment  = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = "Instagram")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp))
            Input(viewModel.username,placeholder = "username"){
                viewModel.username = it
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp))
            Input(viewModel.password,placeholder = "Password"){
                viewModel.password = it
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp))
            Button(onClick = {viewModel.submit()},modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(text = "Sign In")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class SignInViewModel(application:Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var username by mutableStateOf("")
    var password by mutableStateOf("")


    private val context = application.applicationContext
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>(null)
    val user:LiveData<User> get() = _user



    fun submit(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = apolloClient.mutate(LoginMutation(username = Input.fromNullable(username),password = Input.fromNullable(password))).await()
            _user.value = response.data?.login?.user as User

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 1: pass it to your submit function and then invoke it after your check passed

Comment: Option 2: create a ``remember(<keyToUser>) { user.takeIf{it != null}?.let{onLogin.invoke(user)} }`` When your liveData mutates the remember is executed again

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

**1.** First I created this class to communicate from ViewModel to view(s) and to have stateful communication where the UI knows what to show with every update and through one live data.

```
 sealed class UIState<out T>() {
    class Idle() : UIState<Nothing>()
    class Loading(val progress: Int = 0) : UIState<Nothing>()
    class Success<out T>(val data: T?) : UIState<T>()
    class Error(
        val error: Throwable? = null,
        val message: String? = null,
        val title: String? = null
    ) : UIState<Nothing>()
}
```

**2.** Then Of course create the live data in ViewModel and also an immutable copy for the view:

```
    private val _loginState by lazy { MutableLiveData<UIState<ResponseUser>>() }
    val loginState: LiveData<UIState<ResponseUser>> = _loginState

    fun performLogin(username: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _loginState.postValue(loading)
            // your login logic here

            if ("login was successful") {
                _loginState.postValue(UIState.Success("your login response if needed in UI"))
            } else {
                _loginState.postValue(UIState.Error("some error here"))
            }
        }
    }
```

**3.** Now in the UI I need to observe this live data as a state, which is pretty easy we have delegate literally called observeAsState. But here is the catch and that's if you are doing something like navigation, which you only want to happen only once:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
    val loginState by viewModel.loginState.observeAsState(UIState.Idle())
    val hasHandledNavigation = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    if (loginState is UIState.Success && !hasHandledNavigation.value ) {
        navigateToWelcomeScreen()
    else {
        LoginScreenUI(loginState) { username, password ->
            viewModel.performLogin(username, password)
         }
    }
}
```

**4.** in the UI you want, among other things, two text fields and a button, and you want to remember the username and password that entered:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreenUI(
    state: UIState<ResponseUser>, onLoginButtonClicked: (username: String, password: String) -> Unit
) {
    Column() {
        var username by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = username,
            onValueChange = { username = it },
            )

        var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = password,
            onValueChange = { password = it },
            )
        Button(
            onClick = {
                onLoginButtonClicked(
                    username, password
                )
            }
        ) {
           Text(text = "Login")
        }
        if (state is UIState.Error) {
            AlertDialogComponent(state.title, state.message)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I've covered everything :D

Comment: What is the point of having ViewModel when you are using rememberSaveable?

Comment: Do you mean we should save the user name and password as the user enters the string in ViewModel?
I don't think that's necessary since this information is only important if the user presses the login button, and when he does, we will send them entirely to the ViewModel.
If you are asking whats the main point of the ViewModel, well its not recommended to perform background tasks in the UI.

Comment: before Compose  ViewModel main purpose was to hold the state. So when orientation has changed user still got the same data.  I got your point that the data is only used for one business logic, which is login method. Based from my experience on what i have read, it is recommended to put your state inside viewModel, so that you can observe it in composable.

Comment: Great answer that covered all the bases, what is ResponseUser?

Comment: @Val Okafor, response User is the class we created to map the json data we get from backend, which is different for any one

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use the `LaunchedEffect` because the Android developer documentation is mentioning showing SnackBar as an example which is a single time event, code example following the same as [Amin Keshavarzian Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68938491/3321991)

just change the part 3 to use `LaunchedEffect` instead of the flag state `hasHandledNavigation`

```
    @Composable
    fun LoginScreen(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
        val loginState by viewModel.loginState.observeAsState(UIState.Idle())

     LaunchedEffect(key1 = loginState) {
         if (loginState is UIState.Success) 
        navigateToWelcomeScreen()
       }
    
       LoginScreenUI(loginState) { username, password ->
                viewModel.performLogin(username, password)
          
        }
    }
```